# invalid nib registered for identifier (Cell)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, identifier

Getting the following error in my `UITableView` when I drag a segue to another view controller to be pushed.

```
"invalid nib registered for identifier (Cell) - nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a `UITableViewCell` instance"
```

I have a `UITableView` on my storyboard. I put in two static rows in the UITableView via storyboards. I have given these rows a cellIdentifier of "Cell" via the storyboard.

HERE IS MY `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GothamRounded-Light" size:18]];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 13, 300, 30)];
    label.textColor = [UIColor statLightBlue];
    [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Rounded-Light" size:18]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

    if(indexPath.row == 0){
        label.text = @"Credit Card"; // man profile
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CreditCardIcon.png"];    
    } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        label.text = @"Promotion Code"; // credit card
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PromoCodeIcon.png"];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

At this point, it all works great. But here is what I do that causes the error above:

If I control drag from the first `UITableView` cell, in storyboards, to any other random view creating a segue, it causes the error above. If I remove said segue the error goes away.

Any clue on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Its probably case sensitive. you say you identify it as "CELL" but your code uses "Cell"

Comment: you fix your problem?

Comment: No, I didn't fix it.  And I typo'd it is "Cell" in both places.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you give "CELL" and no "Cell" have also a double check if you set the identifier in IB or the Restoration ID, the identifier that you have to set is in "Attributes inspector"

Comment: Sorry it is "Cell" in both above.

Comment: You make an subClass of UITableViewCell? because maybe the problem is that you have a subClass like CustomTableCell set in your nib like your prototype cell and you set its 'Cell' as identifier so when you create an cell you have to make an instance of your subClass and not of a normal UITableViewCell

Comment: because the error means like  that you have the nib of your cell non in your storyboard

Comment: It has nothing to do with a custom nib. I don't have or use a custom nib. I just dragged a uitableview onto the storyboard, which is inside a navigationviewController (standard stuff). The app runs perfectly with storyboard as is and code as is, as long as I don't drag control drag from the cell to another view to create a segue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,  the issue is I had dynamic cells picked in the attribute inspector, but had the code in cellForRowAtIndex wrong.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView
                   cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


[cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Rounded-Light" size:18]];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 13, 300, 30)];
label.textColor = [UIColor statLightBlue];
[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Rounded-Light" size:18]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:label];


if(indexPath.row == 0){
    label.text = @"Credit Card"; // man profile
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CreditCardIcon.png"];

} else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
    label.text = @"Promotion Code"; // credit card
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PromoCodeIcon.png"];
}

return cell;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the similar error using storyboard. Fix it by changing Table View's "Prototype Cells"@"Attributes inspector" to 1.

Answer (score -1):

I stumbled on this as well. My error was `register(nib` call, where 'nib' is not the nib object just loaded. This was the bad code:

```
let myNib = UINib(nibName:"MyCellNib", bundle: nil);

numberMapCollectionView.register(nib, 
                        forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCellNib");

numberMapCollectionView.dataSource = self;
```

And this is the good code, note: `register(myNib` instead of `register(nib`

```
let myNib = UINib(nibName:"MyCellNib", bundle: nil);

numberMapCollectionView.register(myNib, 
                        forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCellNib");

numberMapCollectionView.dataSource = self;
```